# Strange error with multinomial logit regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mlogit

I tried to do multinomial logit regression in R. I used the following command:

fit <- glmnet(xdata, newdata2$state, family="multinomial" )

but I got this error:

**Error: from glmnet Fortran code (error code 8001); Null probability for class 1 < 1.0e-5**

I don't know how should I fix this error and I will be thankful for any help. Also please let me know if there is any easier way to perform multinomial logit regression (and not bionomial) in R.

EDIT:

```
table(newdata2$state)
Bad   D    F    H IND   PR RRT RRT1 RRT2 RRT3
0   722 9691 1273 187 2058 937    0    0    0
```

Comment: what does `table(newdata2$state)` give you?

Comment: Bad    D    F    H  IND   PR  RRT RRT1 RRT2 RRT3 
   0  722 9691 1273  187 2058  937    0    0    0

Comment: This is what I get. Bad, D, F,..., RRT3 are the states of a patient on tommorrow and I am trying to create transition probabilities of moving to each of these states using this multinomial logit model.

Comment: well, it looks like algorithm breaks down because couple of your categories have cell count `0`. Try to exclude these and rerun the analysis...

Comment: If x can be 0, then instead of estimating x, try estimating (x+1). glmnet works fine. Instead of raw glmnet, try using cv.glmnet(nfolds =3 or higher) to get a crossvalidated estimator. It also has the advantage of being pretty robust to class imbalances.

Comment: If RRT1/2/3 can never occur, then exclude them from training. Or if they're just very rare then consider using the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) for rare events.